# C++ Errors C2893, C2780, C2672 when using future, promise, detached thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-errors, c++14, future

I have got a class named `cApp`.

I want to run `CheckProcessList()` in the background until the program terminates. So i thought, well, lets run it in a detached thread until `~cApp()`. I made a bool to break out of the loop in `CheckProcessList()`. In `~cApp` I set the bool true `m_bTerminateThread = true` to break out and wait for the promise `m_barrierFuture->wait()` that the thread has ended execution. After breaking out i set the promise `barrier.set_value()` that the thread is now ending execution. Now `~cApp` can finish execution. Or at least that is my understanding of the things i want to achieve and how to do it. Well, can't be right since i get Compiler Errors.

Why did it want to check if the thread finished in the first place? Because the program breaks at runtime when it terminates and the thread is at that moment in `GetProcId()`. If it is sleeping in the moment of termination the program does not break.

I searched msdn and stackoverflow for answers but i do not get anything out of it that i can understand. I am using VS2019 and C++14. Thank you guys in advance.

> cApp.h

```
#pragma once
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "cMain.h"
#include <thread>
#include <future>

class cApp
    : public wxApp
{
public:
    cApp();
    ~cApp();

    virtual bool OnInit();

private:
    // supposed to run in a detached thread
    // until the program terminates
    void CheckProcessList(std::promise<void> barrier);

    // Checks whether or not the game processes are running
    // this thread runs asynchronous until ~cApp
    std::thread* m_tCheckProcList;
    // used in thread "m_tCheckProcList"
    // if set to true the thread terminates asap
    bool m_bTerminateThread;
    // used in thread "m_tCheckProcList"
    // in ~cApp this future waits for the promise that the thread has finished
    std::future<void>* m_barrierFuture;

    // Dark Souls 3 Processname
    const wchar_t* m_ds3Name;
    // Need for Speed: Most Wanted Processname
    const wchar_t* m_nfsmwName;
    // Serious Sam: The Second Encounter Processname
    const wchar_t* m_sstseName;

    const wxString* m_frameTitle;
    const wxSize* m_frameSize;

    cMain* m_mainFrame;
};
```

> cApp.cpp

```
#include "cApp.h"

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(cApp);

cApp::cApp()
{
    m_ds3Name = L"DarkSoulsIII.exe";
    m_sstseName = L"SeriousSam.exe";
    m_nfsmwName = L"speed.exe";
    m_frameTitle = new wxString("DeltaWin");
    m_frameSize = new wxSize(600, 450);
    m_bTerminateThread = false;
    m_mainFrame = nullptr;
    m_tCheckProcList = nullptr;
    m_barrierFuture = nullptr;
}

cApp::~cApp()
{
    // send the thread the "signal" to finish asap
    m_bTerminateThread = true;
    // wait for thread "m_tCheckProcList" to finish execution
    m_barrierFuture->wait();
}

bool cApp::OnInit()
{
    // create main top-level window
    m_mainFrame = new cMain(*m_frameTitle, wxDefaultPosition, *m_frameSize);
    m_mainFrame->Show();

    // create barrier and instantiate the future for it
    std::promise<void> barrier;
    m_barrierFuture = new std::future<void>(barrier.get_future());

    // start checking for running game processes in asynchronous thread
    m_tCheckProcList = new std::thread(&cApp::CheckProcessList, std::move(barrier));
    m_tCheckProcList->detach();

    return true;
}

void cApp::CheckProcessList(std::promise<void> barrier)
{   
    while (!m_bTerminateThread)
    {
        // Dark Souls 3
        if (GetProcId(m_ds3Name) == 0)
            m_mainFrame->MenuItemEnable(false, menuItem::DarkSouls3);
        else
            m_mainFrame->MenuItemEnable(true, menuItem::DarkSouls3);

        // Need for Speed: Most Wanted
        if (GetProcId(m_nfsmwName) == 0)
            m_mainFrame->MenuItemEnable(false, menuItem::NFSMostWanted);
        else
            m_mainFrame->MenuItemEnable(true, menuItem::NFSMostWanted);

        // Serious Sam: The Second Encounter
        if (GetProcId(m_sstseName) == 0)
            m_mainFrame->MenuItemEnable(false, menuItem::SeriousSamTSE);
        else
            m_mainFrame->MenuItemEnable(true, menuItem::SeriousSamTSE);

        // Sleep 1.5s to save resources
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1500));
    }
    // set the promise that the thread has ended execution
    barrier.set_value();
}
```

edit:
The program terminates after `~cApp`. Therefor i think that in this particular case i do not have to `delete` all of that memory because the os takes care of it.

edit2:

> C2893: Failed to specialize function template
> "unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Ty1 &&,_Types2 &&...)
> noexcept()".
>
> C2780: "unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&) noexcept()":
> expects 1 arguments - 2 provided
>
> C2672: "invoke": no matching overloaded function found

Comment: You have a bunch of memory leaks. You should `delete` allocated memory.

Comment: @bloody i thought it is not necessary in this case to `delete `the memory because it gets freed anyway by the os after the program terminated. That is why i don't `delete` all of that stuff in `~cApp`. Am i wrong on that?

Comment: First - on-one can know it, you just showed the class and not context of it usage (perhaps you create hundreds of those objects). Second - even though - yes - **always** deallocate memory! This is the only good school of programming and getting used to proper memory attention. Or use smart pointers instead of `new` to avoid that burden.

Comment: @bloody My fault then. I added " The program terminates after `~cApp`" to the post in the hope that it makes things clearer. Thank your for your reply!

Comment: You should cite the error messages in the question and not just their numbers. Readers may not be so inclined in examining on the web what those error numbers actually mean.

Comment: @bloody I added it. Thank you for that reply!

Comment: Do search for these error codes though, to get an idea of what's wrong. Further, please don't ask three questions in one! Instead, extract a [mcve] for the first error. If you don't solve the issue yourself doing so, put that into a question here. BTW, as a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m_tCheckProcList = new std::thread(&cApp::CheckProcessList, std::move(barrier));`

I don't know to which lines your errors pertains (you didn't show this) but I suspect at least above statement is wrong.

If you pass an address of a thread procedure to `std::thread` constructor and this procedure is a non-static member function the next argument after must be an address of the object you refer to (after all a non-static member function must have an ***instance*** that it is called on behalf of). `std::promise` is not a type which contains such a function pointer type `&cApp::CheckProcessList` so this cannot work.

If you want to associate that thread with the object that creates it typically such invocation looks like:

```
std::thread(&cApp::CheckProcessList, this, ...
```

Or one can use either a static member function or a free function.

---

`cApp::CheckProcessList(std::promise<void> barrier)`

Another problem in your code is passing a promise object *by value* to the thread function. This means a local copy of the promise but promise is not copyable.
You also can't pass it either by reference or by pointer! because `barrier` is a local variable of `OnInit()` method and as soon as that method finishes that variable gets destroyed anyway - the underlying detached thread will mess around with invalid stackframe or cause *undefined behavior* of any kind. Perhaps you could make the `barrier` a data member or rethink your design.

Be very cautious while dealing with detached threads. They are full of pitfalls when used improperly.

Comment: I went with this `std::thread(&cApp::CheckProcessList, this, ...` solution because if i mark `cApp::CheckProcessList(std::promise<void> barrier)` as static i have to mark all the member variables used in this function as static to and i don't think i want this. I probably rethink the design completly as you said. (using smart pointers and so on) But that is why i used `std::move(barrier)`, to not have to make it a data member since a `promise` should only be used once. That's why i decided to declare in `OnInit()` and just `std::move()` it. I have to learn a lot tho. Thank your for your help!